# What does _M mean in svn status result

Tags: svn

i used "svn merge" command to merge the code change from branch to trunk. After merge finished, i found some files which are not modified in branch were makred "M" in trunk. i diff these files and get below result(for example);

```
xxxxx$ svn diff knife.sh

Property changes on: knife.sh
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mergeinfo
    Merged /branches/development/LTE1227/knife.sh:r12198-14851
```

When i commit the code, i found these file was marked as "_M" in svn editor() like below

```
   2 --This line, and those below, will be ignored--
   ... ...
   10 _M   xxx.sh
   11 _M   knife.sh
   ... ...
```

What does _M mean in svn editor? And I don't want to commit these changes and how i can remove these "_M" files from commit list?

Comment: What does `svn stat` show?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/subversion_users/9jxRgKdUbjY

Comment: @DipuH, svn stat showed that file is modified with "M".

Comment: @bahrep, I don't think i got the answer from that discussion. i still don't know how to avoid such situation.

Comment: @yinwu what Subversion client do you run now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the file has property changes, and in your case it's the `svn:mergeinfo` property.  In SVN 1.7.0 an API was introduced to distinguish between modifications to a file's contents or to its SVN properties.  While a property change looks like this:

```
_M   knife.sh
```

A text-only modification looks like what you'd expect:

```
M   knife.sh
```

The [`svn:mergeinfo`](https://www.open.collab.net/community/subversion/articles/merge-info.html) property is added to files when you merge from a different source into them, i.e. from trunk to branch.  SVN uses this information to remember what has and has not already been merged so it doesn't get merged again.

It's typically good to leave it on (assuming you have a recent version where some bugs with it appearing too often were fixed), but if you really want to get rid of it you can just revert that file.  If it's already committed, use the `propdel` command:

```
svn propdel svn:mergeinfo knife.sh
```